# Prime sequence.

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Suppose we have $ p, q$ where $ p$ and $q$ are twin primes between 6,10000. Now the following sequence $pq + 2$ generates 22 primes . These primes are all in the congruence class $ [1]_{100}$ I've been asked to prove why this is the case. I've spent a good time thinking about it and not got any ideas how to even start. Wondering if someone could give me just a direction at least to follow. Was considering the notion of parity as pq is always going to be odd.

Best regards

Comment: Not following.  $(3,5)$ are twin primes and $17=3\times 5+2$ is a prime.  But $17\not \equiv 1\pmod {100}$.  Similarly with $37=5\times 7+2$.  What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry just realised I didn't write the question particularly well, p, q should be twin primes between 6, and 10000.

Comment: $p,p+2,p(p+2)+2$ are primes implies $p\equiv -1 \bmod 5$

Comment: It doesn't have  to be prime. Like I said in my question only 22 primes are generated this way the first is when  we have (149,151).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the possible remainders $\bmod 10$. The only case where $p, p+2, p(p+2)+2$ may be all primes is $p\equiv 9\pmod {10} $ (otherwise there are factors $2$ or $5$). So we have $p=10q+9$  and then

$$p(p+2)+2 = (10q+9)(10q+11)+2 = 100q^2+200q+101$$

> Therefore $p(p+2)+2 \equiv 1 \pmod {100}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider in which cases the product of two twin primes (above $5$) doesn't end in $3$ (which would make their product plus $2$ end in $5$).

Comment: Will give that a look now thanks for posting :)

Answer (score 2):

The comment by reuns holds the key to the answer. He points out that $p,p+2,p(p+2)+2$ being prime implies that $p\equiv -1 \mod 5$. But consider further that if $p\equiv -1 \mod 5$, then $p+2\equiv 1 \mod 5$, which means that the last digit of $p+2$ must be either $1,6$. But if the digit is $6$, then $p+2$ isn't prime. Therefore, taking odd/even into account, $p+2\equiv 1 \mod 10\Rightarrow p=10m-1$ and $p+2=10m+1$. Therefore $p(p+2)+2\equiv 1 \mod 100$ as you observe.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than considering parity, you might want to consider the situation modulo $6$ to start with.

If our three primes are $p, p+2, p^2+2p+2$ we have $p\equiv -1 \bmod 6$ automatically and as observed in a comment on the question it is easy to check that we require $p\equiv -1 \bmod 5$ to avoid divisibility by $5$

We therefore have $p\equiv -1 \bmod 30$ and $p(p+2)+2\equiv 1 \bmod 900$

Comment: How does mod 6 help any more than mod 2 with finding results mod 100?

Comment: @Arthur Your two primes are $6n+1$ and $6n-1$ and $pq+2=36n^2+1$. That deals with the issue modulo $4$. Then (since the two are prime) we can't have $n\equiv pm 1 \bmod 5$ (we'd have a factor $5$) etc. I was suggesting it as a way into the problem which got further than "parity".

Comment: The two primes are $2n\pm 1$, and $pq+2=4n^2+1$. That deals with the issue modulo $4$ just as well as your suggestion, and you can draw exactly the same conclusions from there. It doesn't get further than "parity" in any way. Mod 6 is just mod 2 and mod 3 combined, and the mod 3 doesn't help us in any way here.

Comment: @Arthur You are right, of course - I was posting before going off to a meeting, and in too much haste. However, looking modulo $6$ and combining with modulo $5$ gives an interestingly stronger result, which I have noted in an amended answer. My instinct with twin primes is to start with $6n\pm 1$ and deal with the case of $3$ separately.